# No argument error in python while using __inti__

Tags: python

I have used double underscores still I am getting no argument error, not really sure why :(

```
class Employee:
    def __inti__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def show_employee_details(self):
        print("name of the employee",self.name)

e1 = Employee("Paul",32,87000,"Male")
```

It shows below error message

```
TypeError: Employee() takes no arguments
```

Comment: `__init__` and not `__inti__`

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `__inti__()` method as `__init__()` and also it will take only `name` and argument according to your current code. If you want to add other details too, add them in your `__init__()` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your method `__init__()` is spelt incorrectly. I think you should correct the spelling of your method